# how can i use ' and " in a code in PHP and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like how i can use a lot of ' and " in a code.

Example:

```
echo 'document.write("<a href='$url'> <img src='{$row["image"]}' border='0' /> </a>");';
```

I tried but i'm getting error. Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rhopercy an image with link href

Comment: You schould escape your HTML attributes.

Comment: What about Smarty templates?

Answer (score 1):

so, you have multi-level problem here:

1. data which is echoed to html, usually should be properly escaped via htmlspecialchars
2. you want to see `document.write("..."...");` in your finally produced html, this will trigger javascript syntax error
3. to avoid this error, you should use `\` before " inside string

`echo 'document.write("<a href=\"' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '\"><img src=\"' . htmlspecialchars($row["image"]) . '\" border=\"0\" /></a>");';`

note: I'm using echo with single quotes, if you're using double quotes - you will have to double `\\`

in case of double quotes your code will look like:

`echo "document.write(\"<a href=\\\"" . htmlspecialchars($url) . "\\\"><img src=\\\"" . htmlspecialchars($row["image"]) . "\\\" border=\\\"0\\\" /></a>\");";`

Comment: @Reto by unbuffered you mean that no single string will be created, but every piece will be output by its own?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to tackle this problem.

**1. Escaping the inner double slashes**

`echo "document.write('<a href=\"$url\"> <img src=\"{$row['image']}\" border=\"0\" /> </a>');";`

**2. Closing your PHP tags and writing javascript**

`?>
document.write('<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" border="0" /> </a>');
<?php`

**3. Using [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax**

`echo <<<EOJS
document.write('<a href="$url"> <img src="{$row['image']}" border="0" /> </a>');
EOJS;`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$row = array("image" => "image.png");
echo "document.write('<a href=\"$url\"> <img src=\"".$row["image"]."\" border=0 /> </a>');";
// output: document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com"> <img src="image.png" border=0 /> </a>');
?>
```

Comment: With your current code the attributes will not end up being quoted, ie `href=http://example.com`

Comment: @FernandoOliveira: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the heredoc syntax:

```
echo <<<EOT
document.write(<a href='{$url}'> <img src='{$row["image"]}' border='0' /> </a>);

EOT;
```

From [phpdocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped, but the escape codes listed above can still be used.
>   Variables are expanded, but the same care must be taken when
>   expressing complex variables inside a heredoc as with strings.

Also note, that

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not
>   be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also
>   important to realize that the first character before the closing
>   identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.
>   This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter
>   must also be followed by a newline.